Drools migration path from version 5
We want to upgrade drools libraries as those are very old (version 5). Please suggest a migration path i.e directly can we go to 9 or we need to move to 7 first and then 9. Thanks

I recommend migrating to version 7.x first (following this guide) and then moving to Apache KIE 10 (upcoming version) once available. You can refer to this document to update from drools 7 to 8 (and 10)

thanks for the recommendation. Any reason for choosing KIE 10 and not drools 9? I mean why should i wait for KIE

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-core/9.44.0.Final

Drools 9 was released my mistake, is not a real release. You should consider it as part of the 8.x stream
